# New environment with marginnote

Tags: environments, marginnote

I'm trying to make a new environment that uses `marginnote` like so:

```
\newenvironment{myname}
{ <some stuff> \marginnote{ }
{ } <other stuff> }
```

so that when I do

```
\begin{myname}
My Text Here
\end{myname}
```

I will see "My Text Here" in a marginnote.

The code, written as I have it, won't work though, since we have these awkward open and close braces for `marginnote` inside of the open/close braces for the code to be executed at the beginning/end of the new environment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you want to go into the `\marginnote`?

Comment: What's the purpose of the environment at all? What is `somestuff` supposed to do? Grabbing the environment body is no option here, I think. Perhaps an argument to the environment is of more use

Comment: I'd like to put into the margin some Python code using the minted package. I'll be doing this over and over again with custom options, hence the desire for a new environment

Answer (score 4):

You can capture the contents of an environment using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,marginnote}

\NewEnviron{myenv}{%
  % <some stuff here>
  \marginnote{\BODY}%
  % <other stuff here>
}

\begin{document}

Here is some text.
\begin{myenv}
My Text Here.  
\end{myenv}
Here is some more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ignorespacesafterend` shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @egreg: In this context, or in general?

Comment: With `\NewEnviron`. I believe it's explained in the manual.

Comment: @egreg: I see now; there is a default `[<final code>]` set.